# How to assign user selection / input to a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, user-input

Let's say I have the following:

```
Select a Number:
<select name="Quantity" id="selection"> 
<option value="Value1">1</option> 
<option value="Value2">2</option> 
<option value="Value3">3</option> 
<option value="Value4">4</option> 
</select>

Enter Something:
<input type="string" name="Input1"/></input>
```

One is a dropdown menu, and one is a box you can type text in.

I want to take what the user selects/types in and assign it to a javascript variable. I then want to pass the variable to a javascript file later in the page.

I believe I can figure out the latter part, but how would I go about assigning the user selection/input to a variable?

Can I do something like var one = document.Quantity.Value; var two = document.Input1.Value; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) method :

```
var select_value = document.querySelector('#selection').value
var input_value = document.querySelector('input[name="Input1"]').value
```

**Note** : `querySelector('input[name="Input1"]')` takes the first input with attribute `name = "Input1"`,you can use `querySelectorAll` to catch them all and loop though the collection.

You can also do it in the other way :

```
var select_value = document.getElementById('selection').value
var input_value = document.getElemenstByName('Input1')[0].value
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and let you know if I have any problems. Appreciate the help and will accept your answer shortly :)

Comment: Just wanted to say I tried it and it worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH :)